# LINQ for ...QueryObjectGraph(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, params string[] children)

Tags: linq, entity-framework

In DAL:

```
public IQueryable<T> QueryObjectGraph(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, params string[] children)
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            dbset.Include(child);
        }

        return dbset.Where(filter);
    }
```

In BLL:

```
public IQueryable<Breed_Translated> QueryObjectGraph(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Breed_Translated, bool>> filter, params string[] children)
    {
        return _r.QueryObjectGraph(filter, children);
    }
```

In Controller:

```
var breeds = _breedTranslatedRepository.QueryObjectGraph(b => b.Culture == culture, new string[] {"Breed", "AnimalType_Breed" }).ToList();
```

**QUESTION: I can get all breed_translateds back but can't figure how to filter by AnimalTypeId?**

I can do it in the DAL like this with Comprehension syntax:

```
var queryTest=from bt in Breed_Translateds
join atb in AnimalType_Breeds
on bt.BreedId equals atb.BreedId
where bt.Culture=="en" && atb.AnimalTypeId ==2
```

But would like to get better at LINQ with extension method syntax: Something like...
var breeds = _breedTranslatedRepository.QueryObjectGraph(b => b.Culture == culture, new string[] {"Breed", "AnimalType_Breed" }).ToList()**.Where(at=>at.AnimalTypeId==3);**

Comment: Can you show your Breed_Translateds and AnimalType_Breeds classes please?  I think that what you want is not too complex at all as long as the relationships are mapped in the entities.

Comment: Thanks for inquiring...I just saw I had this message....With some help I was able to figure it out...related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277089/ef-many-to-many-dbset-include-in-dal-on-genericrepository