# EF Many-to-many dbset.Include in DAL on GenericRepository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I can't get the QueryObjectGraph to add INCLUDE child tables if my life depended on it...what am I missing? Stuck for third day on something that should be simple :-/

DAL:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    private MyLPL2Context dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;


    protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();

        DataContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected MyLPL2Context DataContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
    }

    public IQueryable<T> QueryObjectGraph(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, 
       params string[] children)
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            dbset.Include(child);
        }

        return dbset.Where(filter);
    }
```

...
DAL repositories

```
 public interface IBreed_TranslatedSqlRepository : ISqlRepository<Breed_Translated>
 {
 }

 public class Breed_TranslatedSqlRepository : RepositoryBase<Breed_Translated>, 
    IBreed_TranslatedSqlRepository
 {

    public Breed_TranslatedSqlRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        : base(databaseFactory)
    {}

 }
```

BLL Repo:

```
 public IQueryable<Breed_Translated> 
    QueryObjectGraph(Expression<Func<Breed_Translated, bool>> filter, 
        params string[] children)
    {
        return _r.QueryObjectGraph(filter, children);
    }
```

Controller:

```
  var breeds1 = _breedTranslatedRepository
    .QueryObjectGraph(b => b.Culture == culture, new string[] { "AnimalType_Breed" })
    .ToList();
```

I can't get to `Breed.AnimalType_Breed.AnimalTypeId`  ..I can drill as far as Breed.AnimalType_Breed then the intelisense expects an expression?

Cues if any, DB Tables: bold is many-to-many
Breed, Breed_Translated, **AnimalType_Breed**, AnimalType, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AnimalBreed_Type` represents many to many relation so the `AnimalBreed_Type` property in `Breed_Translated` entity is **collection**! The collection type doesn't have your table properties. You must use `First` or `Single` to get single related entity from this collection and check it's `AnimalTypeId`.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, I am able to start coding again within the hour so I'll wrestle with it some more. thanks again for the advice.

Comment: I got it going using First() !!!!!!!!!! :-) I have to clean it up now [I'll try to anyways..mine is so ugly lol] but thanks for the help x 1000 not being stuck anymore is a great feeling!  Anyways here is what's working :

Comment: var breeds1 = _breedTranslatedRepository.QueryObjectGraph(b => b.Culture == culture, "Breed","Breed.AnimalType_Breed").ToList();

            var breeds2 = breeds1.Where(a => a.Breed.AnimalType_Breed.First().AnimalTypeId == animalTypeId).ToList()
            .Select(a => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = a.BreedNameTranslated,
                Value = a.BreedId.ToString(),
            });

            return Json(breeds2);

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Include it has a return type. Linq is mostly functional so it will NOT alter any objects but rather return new ones. You need to store this new object instead.

Try:

```
var query = dbset.Where(filter);
foreach (var child in children)
{
    query = query.Include(child);
}

return query;
```

OTHER NOTE: You can simplify this:

```
var breeds1 = _breedTranslatedRepository
    .QueryObjectGraph(b => b.Culture == culture, new string[] { "AnimalType_Breed" })
    .ToList();
```

To

```
var breeds1 = _breedTranslatedRepository
    .QueryObjectGraph(b => b.Culture == culture, "AnimalType_Breed")
    .ToList();
```

When you methods takes a params string[] argument

Comment: Hi Mikael, thanks for your input. I will be able to try this and the above out in a little bit. thanks again for your help.

Comment: I cleaned up my passing in string params like you suggested. Thanks :-)

Comment: and cleaned up the include foreach in my repoBase as you illustrated...thank you